# IBM Worklight Rich Page Editor Issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-rpe

Eclipse: Kepler Service Release 2
IBM Worklight: 6.1

My issue is with the rich page editor in worklight. I'm able to see design view with IE selected but upon switching to FireFox i get continuous Loading... The design view in Firefox view never loads. According to worklight documentation Firefox should be part of the product installation so i would think this should be straight forward.

Comment: Do you have any Firefox installed on your system? If so, what version is it? Also, what version of Kepler are you using (Classic or JEE or may be other)? Do you have any other product installed in the same Eclipse? What JDK are you using for all this? By the way, when it is stuck in Loading, have you tried hitting the "Refresh" button in the toolbar? And finally, is this happening with a new clean hybrid app or do you have custom code (HTML/JS/CSS) in it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 64bit flavor of Eclipse in Windows? If using 64bit, then the Safari and Firefox buttons will not work correctly. This is a known limitation of the Rich Page Editor.

Related user documentation topic:

- [Browser requirements for Rich Page Editor](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/com.ibm.rad.worklight.doc/topics/trpebrowsersupportwl.html?lang=en)

To make it work, you need to install the 32bit flavor of Eclipse.